# How to properly code core data drill down with NSSet

Tags: ios, core-data, tableview, nspredicate, drilldown

I’m relatively new at iOS programming and Core Data, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.  In my project I have two entities. Entity (1) is named “Doctor”, entity (2) is “Patient”.  The relationship between Doctor and Patient is named “patients”. The inverse is named “doctor”. I have a one to many relationship made between doctor and patient. The entities have been sub-classed.  I have the root view controller displaying doctor names. I want to be able to select a cell of a doctor and display his patients on the segued view controller. His patients are contained in an NSSet. I’m stumped here. Do I pass that NSSet in the segue code, or do I use a predicate in the fetch request to fetch only the applicable patient names? Any code example you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `Doctor` object obtained when the user tapped the cell to your detail controller. Then in the detail controller use `doctor.patients` (the NSSet). This is the simplest option and will work well if you aren't making any changes to the data. You're probably displaying the patients in a table view so you will want to use `NSSortDescriptor` to organise the patients before displaying them (then they will be in an array and you use `objectAtIndex:`).

If you're going to change the data it'll still work, but you need to know about the change in some way so you can update the UI.

If you already have a fetched results controller, that's fine and will monitor changes for you. In that case use the `doctor` in the predicate format:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"doctor = %@", self.doctor];
```

Either way, pass the doctor object to the new view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Some clarification is needed. Do I need another FRC for the second view controller for the second table view controller, or just pass a reference from the first?

Comment: Each view controller would have it's own FRC. The first is fetching Doctors, the second is fetching Patients.

Comment: Thanks a million. You've been a big help.

Comment: one more question before I try to implement your suggestions this morning. In your predicate example, shouldn't it be "@Patient = %@, self.selectedDoctor". I ask this because the way you wrote it I'm filtering on doctors for the selected doctor which is confusing to me.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Your aim is to show all patients for a specified doctor, right? So you want to search for Patient objects. But the test is that the patients 'doctor' relationship is set to the doctor you're interested in (which is what my predicate does).

Comment: Understand. I just implemented the suggestions you made. The second table view controller is returning all patients. Not just the patients for the selected doctor. Any suggestions?

Comment: When the FRC is created, check you have the doctor set so the predicate is created properly. Check the predicate is set on the fetch request.

Comment: Maybe I'm not saving the patient correctly. I'm not using the core generated assessors to set the value of the patient. Is this necessary?

Comment: I'm unable to use chat on stack yet. Can I send you my email so we can communicate?

Comment: _aNewPatient.patientName = self.patientNameField.text;
That's all that I'm doing to set the patient. The doctor object was passed to the addPatient modal view controller via the segue from the Doctor table view controller

Comment: that's what I'm thinking. I haven't properly linked the patient I've added to the doctor

Comment: I believe I've set that relationship up correctly in the data model

Comment: good suggestion I entered NSLog(@"Doctor Name: %@", self.patient.doctor) in the table view cellForRowAtIndex and got back null.

Comment: Ok, I'll go back and see what I did wrong. Thanks again for your time. I know this is way more then you'd like to spend, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know that I fixed the issue and everything is working and updating properly now. I don't know how to delete all these comments, so please have at it. Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: hate to ask another dumb question, but how do i accept your solution?